# Type conversion with Generic List and Interfaces in C# - Looking for an elegant solution

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

Take the following example (created purely to demonstrate the point). What I am trying to do is isolate one part of the system from another and only want to expose a specific subset of the functionality externally from the assembly while internally working against the full objects methods.

This code compiles, but I get an invalid cast exception at runtime. It feels like this should work but unfortunately it does not.

Can anybody suggest an elegant solution to this problem?

UPDATED: Based on comments I have changed this example to better demonstrate the issue, I also in the sample now show the solution that worked for me...

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace Test
    {
        public class PeopleManager
        {
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

            public PeopleManager()
            {
            }

            public void CreatePeople()
            {               
                people.Add(new Person("Joe", "111 aaa st"));
                people.Add(new Person("Bob", "111 bbb st"));
                people.Add(new Person("Fred", "111 ccc st"));
                people.Add(new Person("Mark", "111 ddd st"));                
            }

            public IList<IName> GetNames()
            {
                /* ERROR
                 * Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Test.Person>' 
                 * to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Test.IName>' c:\notes\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs
                 */

                return (List<IName>) people; // <-- Error at this line

                // Answered my own question, do the following

                return people.ConvertAll(item => (IName)item);
            }
        }

        public interface IName
        {
            string Name { get; set; }
        }

        internal class Person : IName
        {
            public Person(string name, string address)
            {
                this.Name = name;
                this.Address = address;
            }

            public string Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string Address
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please only include the snippits that are directly related to your issue?

Comment: Does it have to be an `IList`? Can it be an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Hey Guys, sorry if this wasn't clear but the reason I am casting here is because the class, Person in this instance in my code has 1000's of lines of proprietary logic in it. Within the implementing assembly I want access to all the functionality of the class. However outside the assembly I just want to expose the classes client specific interface.... Doing this worked great for me: List<IName> restricted = people.ConvertAll(item => (IName) item);

Comment: I thought I would also share this since it relates to the problem of domain mapping. I found a project called AutoMapper which on a larger scale might be a better solution to use. Here is the link for more info: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/01/22/automapper-the-object-object-mapper.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
IList<IName> restricted = people.Cast<IName>().ToList();
```

Comment: Marked as answer - important to not this is only in .net 3.5 and above. The ConvertAll answer I used in my solution works in .net 2.0 and above.

Answer (score 3):

`Person` inherits from `IName` but `List<Person>` does not inherit from `List<IName>`. Imagine if it did: you'd be able to cast a `List<Person>` to its superclass, `List<IName>`, then add an instance of `IName` that was not an instance of `Person`!

Just make your `List<Person>` a `List<IName>`--that should be sufficient.

Comment: If I do that, in my internal classes I would have to keep casting the list, thanks though

Comment: @vulkanino, why do you think this is the "correct" answer?  Do you mean to suggest the other solutions somehow won't work?

Comment: Other solutions *may* work, but jonathan's answer is an example of good OO design, while *any* cast is not! I know this is a strong assertion, but I think it is true. In you example a Person IS a IName, thanks to polymorphism, and that's one of the reasons Interfaces are so good and so much used. You should strive for a design that won't force you to examine a type in runtime (typeof) or try to cast between types. Instead, you should try to always program to interfaces, not to object instances.

Comment: vulkanino: A `Person` *is* an `IName`, but it also has an `Address`. When somebody who needs an `Address` gets his `List<IName>`, they'll have to cast. So how is that design better?

Comment: His code doesn't indicate that the list is used outside of a particular function; only that it needs to be used as a `List<IName>`. If he needs to treat the elements as `Person` instances, he should have a `List<Person>`, but the code and his comments suggest this is not the case for this particular question.

Comment: The true use case I have is I have a complex class with lot of functions that gets used within the assembly, when exposed from the assembly, I only want the caller to be able to perform a very limitied subset of operations on what will be a recursive tree structure. All the internal workings of the nodes are of no interest to the caller. Contrary to other posts here, I believe it to be good OO design to only expose the limited interface from the assembly so users of the data can't shoot themselves in the foot. I could makea limited clone but this has perf issues.

Comment: Then you should expose as your interface the bare minimum that fulfills your class's contract. If your class is responsible for maintaining an (ordered or unordered) set of `Person` instances, then it should be doling out `IList<Person>` or even `ICollection<Person>`. *Within* your class, you can feel free to use concrete types--`List<Person>` or `List<IName>` or whatever you need for the particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question but thought I would post in case anybody else runs into this in the future. At the line where the error occurs you can actually do this which is pretty nifty:

```
List<IName> restricted = people.ConvertAll(item => (IName) item);
```

Comment: I prefer Elisha's answer.  Operates on IEnumerable<T> so is useful in far more situations.

Comment: good to know :) thanks - here I wanted to use findall so IEnumerable didn't work but generally I agree

Comment: @Kirk - just good to know, the Cast is .net 3.5 and above, ConvertAll is .net 2.0. My project has to be 2.0 so I couldn't use Cast

Answer (score 1):

I would create a class to wrap the one collection (for performance) rather than make a copy like every other solution on the page.

```
public class CovariantList<TType, TBase> : IList<TBase>
where TType:TBase,class
{
private IList<TType> _innerList;

public int Count
{
get
{
return this._innerList.Count;
}
}

public TBase this[int index]
{
get
{
return this._innerList[index];
}
set
{
TType type = value as TType;
if(type!=null)
{
...
}
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<IName> restricted = people.ToList<IName>();
```

little shorter than

```
IList<IName> restricted = people.Cast<IName>().ToList();
```